# How to move to a specific page programmatically in Clarity data grid

Tags: datagrid, pagination, vmware-clarity

I using a server driven clarity data grid and want to move to a specific page programmatically.

Comment: Can you post some code of urs for reference?

Comment: This isn’t very clear, but you use the Angular Router to move programmatically. What does this have to do with Clarity exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datagrid pagination offers a `[(clrDgPage)]` two-way binding. Please note that the page numbers start on 1, not 0.

You can check out https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/datagrid/pagination for more information.